# Failed to resolve: com.google.android.gms:play-services-appindexing:11.0.0

Tags: android

I'm getting this message in android studio:
Failed to resolve: com.google.android.gms:play-services-appindexing:11.0.0...
What do I have to do?
 My Gradle: app-

```
dependencies {
compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
    exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
})
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.3.1'
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:11.0.1'
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:11.0.1'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-appindexing:11.0.0'
compile 'com.android.support:design:25.3.1'
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:11.0.1'
testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

I've recived this message from the start.
Thank you so much.

Comment: try cleaning your project

Comment: yet again,   > Could not find com.google.android.gms:play-services-appindexing:11.0.0.

Answer (score 5):

Try update or install Google Repository

Tools -> SDK Manager -> Google Repository

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Have you added google maven repo?

```
repositories {
    // google before jcenter to avoid mailicious artifacts
    maven { url 'https://maven.google.com' } // or simple google() on gradle 4.0+
    jcenter()
    ...
}
```

Comment: No... I don't have that issue with my other projects, and I've never faced this. What do I do with it?

Comment: ahh, its google services. they are not available on maven repo. update your sdk to google repo 54 with next command `sdkmanager "extras;google;m2repository"`